# Solve differential equation $x^3y'''+xy'-y=x\ln(x)-x,x>0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation $x^3y'''+xy'-y=x\ln(x)-x,x>0$.

I observe $y=x$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For the homogeneous equation
$$x^3y'''+xy'-y=0$$
If $y=x^m$ we get $y'=mx^{m-1},\;\;y''=m(m-1)x^{m-2},\quad\text{and}\quad y'''=m(m-1)(m-2)x^{m-3}$, then
$$x^3y'''+xy'-y=0\qquad\iff\qquad x^m[m(m-1)(m-2)+m-1]=0\quad\text{for all }x>0$$
which implies
\begin{align*}
m(m-1)(m-2)+m-1&=0\\
(m-1)(m^2-2m+1)&=0\\
(m-1)^3&=0
\end{align*}
Since $1$ is a root of multiplicity $3$ it follows $$y_c=c_1x+c_2x\ln x+c_3x(\ln x)^2$$
Now, you may use variation of parameters in order to find a particular solution $y_p$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fullfil Angel's answer, you should continue rising power of $\ln x$, so particular solution should be $y_p=ax\ln^3 x+bx\ln^4 x$
$$x^3y_p'''+xy_p'-y_p=6ax+24bx\ln x$$
So $a=-1/6$ and $b=1/24$